# Python and percentages

Tags: python, percentage, multiplication

Is there a proper way to handle percentages in Python?

For example, how to handle the value `0.01` and make it displayed as `1%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use str.format()

```
percentage = 0.01
print "{0:.0f}%".format(percentage * 100)
```

1%

```
percentage = 0.0142
print "{0:.0f}%".format(percentage * 100)
```

1%

```
percentage = 0.0142
print "{0:.1f}%".format(percentage * 100)
```

1.4%

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by a hundred then convert to `int`

```
>>> int(0.01 * 100)
1
```

As a function

```
def dec_to_pct(i):
    return int(i*100)

>>> dec_to_pct(0.01)
1
>>> dec_to_pct(0.07)
7
>>> dec_to_pct(0.42)
42
```

*Note*
If you'd like to preserve remaining decimals, just leave off the conversion to `int`, e.g.

```
>>> 0.4273 * 100
42.73  # percent
```

Comment: Woah, it turned out that i suck even more than I'd expected, how can this be done with a variable? Let's say the user entered a value, and it turned out to be 0.19, however i do not want it to display 0.19, but 19.23 or sth like this, how can this be done?

Comment: If the variable is `x`, then you would say `x *= 100`

Comment: Mhm, yes I did enter it and it worked, but I just can't understand, why? I mean why "*=" ?

Comment: @SteliyanPetrov The operation `x *= 100` is a short-hand (actually it is subtly different) way of writing `x = x * 100`

Comment: @CoryKramer Your answer is excellent and certainly got my upvote, but I prefer pct for the percent instead of perc, and it seems more accepted. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentage I don't think this matters enough for an edit because I looked at PEP 8, and there doesn't seem to be any Python-specific guidance beyond reflecting English language.

Comment: @PaluMacil Fair enough :)